# Ripple effect weird behavior in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, material-design, listviewitem, rippledrawable

I have implemented the ripple effect for each item inside the `ListView` by using `<ripple>` element. I got the desired ripple effect when I touch (select) on each item in the `ListView`. But when I scroll the `ListView` and then select any item again the ripple disappears very fast (almost unnoticeable). I don't know why the ripple appears nicely on some `ListView` items and very weird on some.

My customized ripple layout is shown below (ripple_background.xml)

```
<ripple
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/light_black_overlay">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/background_light" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Layout for the item inside `ListView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:minHeight="?android:listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/ripple_background"> <!--My ripple layout-->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/someText
        android... />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/someImage
        android... />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Has anyone faced this kind of weird ripple effect inside your `ListView`? Any idea if the ListView's recycling mechanism has to do something with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing ripple effect to each item of your list try this:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/yourListView"
        ...
        android:listSelector="@drawable/ripple_background" />
```

Comment: Thanks Saeed, this worked for me. But do you have any idea why it's not working if I use the ripple background for each item inside the listview?

Comment: Actually there is a way that ripple works for each item, i'm not sure but i think you should create a custom adapter and while you're binding view check whether item needs to show ripple or not(by storing state of each item) and some other handling like that.